# create a table with psycopg2 fail

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

i am making a script with python were every time it runs starts fresh, there for i want to make sure i delete the database and table and recreate them.
i was following this tutorial: https://www.fullstackpython.com/blog/postgresql-python-3-psycopg2-ubuntu-1604.html
but instead matt as a user a did osboxes, but when i try to create the table i get the error that already exists,  how can that be if i previously dropped the database?

```
# connect to postgres
connection = psycopg2.connect(dbname="postgres", user="osboxes", password="osboxes.org", host="localhost")
connection.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
cursor = connection.cursor()
# create database to work on
name_database = "image_comparation"
cursor.execute("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS {0};".format(name_database))
cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE {0};".format(name_database))

name_table = "IMAGES"    
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {0};".format(name_table))

# here is the issue,  never creates the table
try:
    # cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {0};".format(name_table))
    create_table_query = """CREATE TABLE {0} (IMAGE_PATH TEXT NOT NULL, IN_PROGRESS BOOLEAN, COMPLETED BOOLEAN, TIME_PROCESS REAL, CREATED_TIME timestamp, MATCHES TEXT NULL, MOVED BOOLEAN);""".format(name_table)
    cursor.execute(create_table_query)
    connection.commit()
except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
    print(f'Error {e}')
```

> > > Error relation "images" already exists

the first time i run the scripts works after that tell me tha relation ship allready exist so i asume that the table some how persisted, so i checked in the cmd

```
psql (12.3 (Ubuntu 12.3-1.pgdg18.04+1), server 12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-4))
Type "help" for help.

image_db=> \dt
Did not find any relations.
image_db=>
```

then i manually copy the create table query into the psql and does work fine. i am missing something?

Comment: works fine when I tried, without any issue!

Comment: maybe something in the vm that i am using? i will try to put a delay between the actions and check.

Comment: very strange if i do another script and i just make the connection directly to that  new database and create the table, does work, but in the original script doesn't =(.... need to investigate more.

Answer (score 0):

you are logging into the default database 'postgres',  think as the master database that hold information about every thing else that is happening in postgre,
then you create a new database,
but you need to create another connection to that that base to switch to it, right now you are creating a table in the 'master' database,
add

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(dbname="image_comparation", user="osboxes", password="osboxes.org", host="localhost")
```

to switch to that database and then create the tale.

Answer (score -1):

I suddenly started having trouble creating tables as well.  I discovered that I forgot to include a commit statement.  Try modifying your connection (below for Python):

```
conn.autocommit = True
```

or add a `conn.commit()`.

Comment: The OP is committing, you can see it in their code.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34819540)